# Greedy algorithm minimum search in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ assignment which I've been working on in the last 2 weeks. My knowledge is very limited, as I just started learning C++ and algorithms in February.

The assignment is:
N number of guests were invited to a party. We know all guests arrival and leave time. We want to know which guest met the LEAST amount of other guests. Two guests meet when guest1_arrivaltime <= guest2_leavetime and guest2_arrivaltime <= guest1_leavetime. If there are multiple guests who met the same amount of other guests, only one needs to be printed out.

Use: standard input (cin, cout) and greedy algorithm.

N (number of guests) can range from 1 to 1 000 000, the arrival and leave time values can be between 1 and 100 000

Run time limitation: 0.1 second

Memory limitation: 32 MB

I have a working code which seems to be okay to me, but when I upload it to the school's server I only get 27 marks out of 100. I need 50 marks to pass.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct guestData
{
    int guestIndex;
    int time;

    guestData(int guestIndex, int time)
    {
        this->guestIndex = guestIndex;
        this->time = time;
    }

    guestData()
    {
        guestIndex = 0;
        time = 0;
    }
};

int n;
guestData * arrive;
guestData * leave;
set<int> guestsIn;
set<int> * metSet;
int minGuests;
int minIndex = 1;

bool operator<(const guestData & l, const guestData & r)
{
    return l.time < r.time;
}

void read(int n)
{
    arrive = new guestData[n];
    leave = new guestData[n];
    metSet = new set<int>[n];
    minGuests = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int arriveTime;
        int leaveTime;
        cin >> arriveTime >> leaveTime;
        arrive[i] = guestData(i, arriveTime);
        leave[i] = guestData(i, leaveTime);

    }
}

void process()
{
   sort(arrive, arrive+n);
   sort(leave, leave+n);

   int i = 0, j = 0;

   while (i < n && j < n)
   {
      if (arrive[i].time <= leave[j].time)
      {
            int currentTime = arrive[i].time;
            int in = arrive[i].guestIndex;
            for (auto it = guestsIn.begin(); it != guestsIn.end(); ++it)
            {
                metSet[in].insert(*it);
                metSet[*it].insert(in);
            }
            guestsIn.insert(in);
          i++;
      }
      else
      {
          int currentTime = leave[j].time;
            int out = leave[j].guestIndex;
           guestsIn.erase(out);
          j++;
      }
   }
}

void findMin(){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (metSet[i].size() < minGuests)
        {
            minGuests = metSet[i].size();
            minIndex = i+1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    read(n);
    process();
    findMin();
    cout << minIndex << " " << minGuests;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem: it works great on the example input, which is:

8

1 3

4 8

9 12

2 5

3 9

7 10

2 3

1 3

where 8 is the n (number of guests) and then 8 x the arrival(left row) and leave time(right row) for the guests.

The output for this example input is: 3 2 which is correct, because the 3rd guests met the least amount of other guests (2)

However, I get this error on my school's website when I upload my code: ERROR CODE 11 ILLEGAL MEMORY REFERENCE

Comment: Try some other inputs to see if you can get the same error yourself. Try some edge cases, like having met the same amount of guests, 1 to 1 000 000 guests and 1 to 1 000 000 arrival/leave times.

Comment: Why are you using `new`? There's no need for it. Use `std::vector` for arrays. If you run in debug mode, `operator[]` probably checks bounds.

Comment: I may miss something, but in `process()` I don't understand what happens when `i` and `j` corresponds to the same guest. I guess it should be treated differently

Comment: Have you tried your code for some big values of n? You mention a time limit on this.

Comment: In the worst case, memory size and complexity can be O(N^2), i.e. O(10^12)

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to ask homework questions. Kindly read about the scope of StackOverflow before asking questions here.

Comment: @ArkaMukherjee It seems that there is not a strict official position for homework questions. However, according to this link, they are acceptable if some conditions are fulfilled: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please have a read through this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: You need a different algorithm. Try your with the max possible N and see how long it takes

Answer (score 0):

You should free the memory at the end of the program. The grading system probably detects you are not doing that.

```
delete[] arrive;
delete[] leave;
delete[] metSet;
```